# reading xls file in php using codeigniter with Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader library

Tags: php, codeigniter, programming-languages

am trying to read an excel file (i.e xls) and import the data to mysql database and am using codeigniter 2.0.1 framework.

here are the codes to generate query

```
    public function read_file($table = 'organization', $filename = 'test.xls') {

    $pathToFile = './uploads/' . $filename;
    $this->load->library('Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader');
    $data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader($pathToFile);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $table (";
    for($index = 1;$index <= $data->sheets[0]['numCols']; $index++){
        $sql.= strtolower($data->sheets[0]['cells'][1][$index]) . ", ";
    }

    $sql = rtrim($sql, ", ")." ) VALUES ( ";
    for ($i = 2; $i <= $data->sheets[0]['numRows']; $i++) {
        for ($j = 1; $j <= $data->sheets[0]['numCols']; $j++) {
            $sql .= "\"" . $data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][$j] . "\", ";
        }
        echo  rtrim($sql, ", ")." ) <br>";
    }

}
```

the values generated in the loop are duplicated , i cant find the problem with the loop...

Here is the result after running the function above:

```
INSERT INTO organization (userid, datestamp, kata, kaya, kaya_zenye_vuoo, vyoo_vyenye_bamba, mifuniko, matumizi_mifuniko, uzuiaji_inzi, usafishikaji_sakafu, usitiri, uezekaji, milango_inayofungika, harufu, wadudu, sabuni, maji, vibuyuchirizi ) VALUES ( "mpwapwa@live.com", "2011-04-10 08:21", "Chunyu", "2", "4", "5", "3", "56", "5", "6", "8", "45", "7", "8", "9", "8", "9", "8" ) 
INSERT INTO organization (userid, datestamp, kata, kaya, kaya_zenye_vuoo, vyoo_vyenye_bamba, mifuniko, matumizi_mifuniko, uzuiaji_inzi, usafishikaji_sakafu, usitiri, uezekaji, milango_inayofungika, harufu, wadudu, sabuni, maji, vibuyuchirizi ) VALUES ( "mpwapwa@live.com", "2011-04-10 08:21", "Chunyu", "2", "4", "5", "3", "56", "5", "6", "8", "45", "7", "8", "9", "8", "9", "8", "annie@yahoo.com", "2011-04-10 08:21", "Chunyu", "2", "4", "5", "3", "56", "5", "6", "8", "45", "7", "8", "9", "8", "9", "8" ) 
INSERT INTO organization (userid, datestamp, kata, kaya, kaya_zenye_vuoo, vyoo_vyenye_bamba, mifuniko, matumizi_mifuniko, uzuiaji_inzi, usafishikaji_sakafu, usitiri, uezekaji, milango_inayofungika, harufu, wadudu, sabuni, maji, vibuyuchirizi ) VALUES ( "mpwapwa@live.com", "2011-04-10 08:21", "Chunyu", "2", "4", "5", "3", "56", "5", "6", "8", "45", "7", "8", "9", "8", "9", "8", "annie@yahoo.com", "2011-04-10 08:21", "Chunyu", "2", "4", "5", "3", "56", "5", "6", "8", "45", "7", "8", "9", "8", "9", "8", " sam@yahoo.com", "2011-04-10 08:21", "Chunyu", "2", "4", "5", "3", "56", "5", "6", "8", "45", "7", "8", "9", "8", "9", "8" )
```

Sorry i cant post images as i'm a newbie.

Thanx in advance..Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot test it, but... :

```
    public function read_file($table = 'organization', $filename = 'test.xls') {

    $pathToFile = './uploads/' . $filename;
    $this->load->library('Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader');
    $data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader($pathToFile);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $table (";
    for($index = 1;$index <= $data->sheets[0]['numCols']; $index++){
        $sql.= strtolower($data->sheets[0]['cells'][1][$index]) . ", ";
    }

    $sql = rtrim($sql, ", ")." ) VALUES ( ";
    for ($i = 2; $i <= $data->sheets[0]['numRows']; $i++) {
        $valuesSQL = '';
        for ($j = 1; $j <= $data->sheets[0]['numCols']; $j++) {
            $valuesSql .= "\"" . $data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][$j] . "\", ";
        }
        echo $sql . rtrim($valuesSql, ", ")." ) <br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: thanx a lot for helping out..The values of $valuesSQL is overwiten as we are assigning different values to the same variable i think putting them in an array will be the best practice.. Can u please explain to me why the codes failed in the first place?..thanx u very much u saved my day..

Comment: First in your $sql you kept INSERT INTO... VALUES ( and then you concatenate to this string all the rows and cols. Instead, I was using for every row the initial $sql and concatenate it with cells from that row.